# How to cite an introduction to a historical primary source using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I am using the [biblatex-chicago](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago?lang=en) package and Chicago Manual of Style 17. What is the best way to implement the recommendations in section [14.110: Introductions, prefaces, afterwords, and the like](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part3/ch14/psec110.html) for citing an introduction to a historical text (e.g. Freud's *Civilization and Its Discontents*) written by another author (e.g. Christopher Hitchens)?

The footnote example given in that section of the Chicago Manual of Style is as follows:

> 2. Christopher Hitchens, introduction to *Civilization and Its Discontents*, by Sigmund Freud, trans. and ed. James Strachey (New York: W. W. Norton, 2010).

I am wondering how to cite this author in bibtex-chicago so that the footnote matches this style. For example, is this something that can be accomplished using @inbook, or is something like @misc needed? The following will not work by itself:

```
@inbook{hitchens,
  editor={Christopher Hitchens},
  title={Introduction},
  year={2010},
  author={Sigmund Freud},
  booktitle={Civilization and Its Discontents},
  publisher={W. W. Norton},
  address={New York}
}
```

Comment: biblatex provides the entrytype `suppbook` for such purposes ("this type is provided for elements such as prefaces, introductions, forewords, afterwords, etc."). I'm not sure how `biblatex-chicago` handles the type, but you can try it out (I can't, for the lack of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `biblatex-chicago`'s documentation regarding the entrytype `suppbook`:

> This is the entry type to use if the main focus of a reference is supplemental material in a book or in a collection, e.g., an introduction, afterword, or forward, either by the same or a different author. [...][I] have also added functionality which allows you to cite any sort of supplemental material whatever, using the `type` field. Under this system, simply put the nature of the material, including the relevant preposition, in that field, beginning with a lowercase letter so biblatex can decide whether it needs capitalization depending on the context. Examples might be "preface to" or "colophon of."

Given that, you could use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@suppbook{hitchens,
  author={Christopher Hitchens},
  type = {introduction to},
  introduction = {xxx},
  date={2010},
  bookauthor={Sigmund Freud},
  title={Civilization and Its Discontents},
  translator = {James Strachey},
  editor = {James Strachey},
  publisher={W. W. Norton},
  location={New York}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\footcite{hitchens}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]